# Find quantiles of gamma like distribution

Tags: r, statistics

The data is gamma like distributed.

[image]

To replicate the data would be something like this:

a) first find the distrib. parameters of the true data:

```
fitdist(datag, "gamma", optim.method="Nelder-Mead")
```

b) Use the parameters shape, rate, scale to simulate data:

```
data <- rgamma(10000, shape=0.6, rate=4.8, scale=1/4.8)
```

To find quantiles using the qgamma function in r, would be just:

EDIT:

```
qgamma(c(seq(1,0.1,by=-0.1)), shape=0.6, rate =4.8, scale = 1/4.8, log = FALSE)
```

How I can find quantiles for my true data (not simulated with rgamma)?

Please note that the quantile r function returns the desired quantiles of the true data (datag) but these are as I understand assuming the data are normally distributed. As you can see they are clearly not.

```
quantile(datag, seq(0,1, by=0.1), type=7)
```

What function in r to use or otherwise how to obtain statistically the quantiles for the highly skewed data?

In addition, would this make sense somewhat? But still not getting the lower values!

```
Fn <- ecdf(datag)
Fn(seq(0.1,1,by=0.1))
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that you think that `quantile` is assuming your data to be normal. What does normality have to do with how the quantile is calculated?

Comment: Ok, I'll be more explicit. `quantile` does not assume that your data is normal. Can you expand on what is wrong with the output from `quantile`?

Comment: @Joran. I mean "quantile" as r function as stated above. I thought that the function (or in general) has the assumption of normality. As you pointed out it is not the case. So is the quantile (r function) applicable to any data? Sorry I'm not familiar with the math behind the quantile function (or just forgot).

Comment: Raw quantiles are generally calculated from the order statistics in your actual data; in effect you are using the ecdf based on your actual data. I remain (fairly) certain that you simply want to use the function `quantile()`.

Comment: @Joran. The data (x-axis) is a probability, ranging from 0 to 1. I'm willing to assign states to each interval (quantile i.e. range 0-10%, 10%-20%, etc.) but I find up to 60% very low values and after 60% it goes quick to 1.

Comment: @ Max: Just like the `mean`, `sd`, `skewness` and `kurtosis`, `quantile` doesn't assume any distribution. This is true not just for `R` but also for other programs.

Comment: So when using as above with quantile: I have state 1 for first range 0%-10% than 10%-20% is state 2 .... state 5 is range 40%-50% but probability 0.60 and 0.40 differ in states only by 1 step = state 5 and state 6.

Comment: @Ricardo. Thanks but I know what the quantile is. There is deeper case/issue I'm having so Wiki is not the right source to look at, believe me.

Answer (score 5):

Quantiles are returned by the "q" functions, in this case `qgamma`. For your data the eyeball integration suggests that most of the data is to the left of 0.2 and if we ask for the 0.8 quantile we see that 80% of the data in the estimated distribution is to the left of:

```
 qgamma(.8, shape=0.6, rate=4.8)
#[1] 0.20604
```

Seems to agree with what you have plotted. If you wanted the 0.8 quantile in the sample you have, then just:

```
 quantile(datag, 0.8)
```

Comment: Of course dgamma returns densities. Its a typo. As you can see the text above the line of code says qgamma. Thanks.